# Cannot use "FrameLayout", error: "Element FrameLayout must be declared" [Android Studio]

Tags: android, react-native, android-framelayout

I am doing a small bit of Android development on a React Native project and I cannot work out how to "import" FrameLayout. I'm sure it is very simple but after an hour of Googling I am stumped.

Please see the error below:

[image]

Thanks,
Al

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1) Probably your XML has been corrupted. Try creating a new one.

2) Have you created it under res/layout path?

Comment: It was because the layout file was in `res/drawable` which is what a tutorial suggested I did. Weirdly it was working in that directory before, but perhaps because I was using layer-list, item and bitmap? Thank you :)

Comment: Exactly. The layer-lists with items and bitmaps fall exactly into the drawables.

Out of curiosity, you can try creating a layer list,inside res/layout. You will get the same error as FrameLayout!